# Proper way to return nested JSON response from a django-rest-framework backend

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've been using django-rest-framework at a high-level for a while, but I'm still relatively new to web api's and I'm not entirely sure what the best practice is for structuring the serializers for handling related data. Here is an example of what I've got setup (this is a watered-down version of what I've got).

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    budget = models.FloatField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="projects")
```

serializers.py

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Client
        fields = (
            'id',
            'url',
            'client_name',
            'email',
        )


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = models.Project
        fields = (
            'id',
            'url',
            'project_name',
            'budget',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'client',
        )
```

views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ClientSerializer


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer
```

Now to my question... What is 'Best Practice' for returning related data in a json response?  Per the above example, I can request the project list and in one api call, I can also cache the related client info in my redux store as well.  However, when I add a project, I have to structure the POST with a fully fleshed out Client object instead of just a primary key.  I've been able to make it work by setting up a nested serializer for the GET and for the POST using the default PrimaryKeyRelatedField, but this seems counter-intuitive... Here is how I see my options:

1. Spend the extra time coding the api views to use nested serializers for GET and PK serializer for POST/UPDATE as described above.
2. Use the same serializer with PrimaryKeyRelatedFields or HyperLinkedRelatedFields for all http requests, but then have to daisy chain api calls in my redux client so that I can collect and display the related information (I wouldn't think it would be good practice to hit the api multiple times like this expecially when the nested structure could get deep with a more complex model).

For a more general question, what is the accepted practice for daisy chaining api calls (GET /projects/ => for-each project GET /client/:id). This seems like it would be a big no-no, but maybe I'm wrong... My understanding is that you will get throttled on public api's doing this. Is that correct?

Comment: If your serializers represent models, you can just set the depth value: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: For daisy-chaining you can use Hyperlinked Serializers: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer

Comment: I'd go with the same approach. In order to daisy-chain requests on the client side, I'd suggest that you use [redux-sagas](https://www.google.de/search?q=redux+sagas&oq=redux+sagas&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2.1780j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I didn't know about the depth values.  That will be useful.  I definitely use redux-saga.  I much prefer it over thunks and can definitely see that it would be useful in this case.  I'm just curious if it's considered good practice to hit an api many times consecutively.  I think the authorized rate limit on githubs api is 5000 / hr, which I guess is quite a lot if your caching you api responses.  And using conditional api requests.  Thanks again for the help!